# Using Methods inside Computed Properties in vueJs

Tags: methods, properties, vue.js

I'm trying to call a method inside of a computed property. My code is more complicated, but calling the method doesn't seem to even work in this simple example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    x: 1
  },
  methods: {
    augmented: function(variable) {
      return (2 * variable);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    doubleX: function() {
      return augmented(this.x);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <input type="number" v-model="x"> result: {{ doubleX }}
</div>
```

As you can see by running the snippet, the value of `doubleX` is not getting rendered.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to reference your component's methods via `this`:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    x: 1
  },
  methods: {
    augmented: function(variable) {
      return (2 * variable);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    doubleX: function() {
      return this.augmented(this.x);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="vue-instance">
  <input type="number" v-model="x"> result: {{ doubleX }}
</div>
```

Comment: Great Thanks for you sir :)
Still have a question, is it possible to call a function directly into the html ?
meaning can i do something like
result: {{ augmented(2) }}

Comment: Yep just like that `{{ augmented(2) }}`

Comment: @SanjaysinhZala If you're saying that you have a computed property called `augmented` and you want to reference the value of that property in your template, then you would just write `{{ augmented }}`

Comment: @thanksd i am saying that if doubleX and augmented both are in computed then how augmented property will call from doubleX.

Comment: @SanjaysinhZala Within a computed, you can reference other computed just like regular properties (i.e. `this.augmented` or `this.doubleX`). See the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html